# How to access private variables in another page by function?

Tags: php

`randomClass.php`

```
class randomClass
{

    private $perPage = 8;
    private $startPage = 0;

    function perPage($perPage)
    {
        $this->db->perPage = $perPage;
    }

    function startPage($startPage)
    {
        $this->db->startPage = $startPage;
    }

    public function usingBothVariables()
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT rndm FROM table LIMIT ?, ?");
        $sth->execute(array($this->startPage, $this->PerPage));

        $row = $sth->fetchAll();
        return $row;
    }
{
```

`index.php`

```
if($randomVariable < 1)
   use startPage function here = 0;
else 
   use startPage function here = $randomVariable * use $perPage function here;
```

Comment: Your "question" doesn't contains any single English setences. So please ask a clear question! Can you modify this class?

Comment: You might want to read the PHP reference on "scope" and "accessors"

Comment: You don't "call" variables. You access or refer to them. You *call* functions.

Comment: Make a getter for those variables

Comment: Well, I edited the title to "access". @wumm, It didn't seem that a set of "sentences" was needed as I asked the question in the index.php page, it was clearly understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In randomClass:

```
public function getPerPage(){ 
  return $this->perPage;
}
public function getStartPage(){ 
  return $this->startPage;
}
```

Now in your index.php you can call those methods to get yuor variables.